# How to update the windows app screenshots in the Microsoft store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, screenshot

I submitted a windows app to Microsoft store, now I need to update the screenshots of the store app. For that, I created a new submission, but I didn't see the already uploaded screenshots on my submission 2.
[image]

On which tab I can update the screenshots?

**Screenshot When clicking on English**

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update the `Store listings` by clicking on the respective languages.
In your case that is `English (United States)`

Comment: Store listing is not clickable

Comment: There are 3 options in the store listing tab, I check all 3, but didn't find already uploaded screenshots

Comment: I clarified my answer

Comment: I clicked on Englih and there is no other informations other than language

Comment: Remove language is only there

Comment: When clicking on English (United States) under store listings you should see and be able to update your application description including the screenshots.
For this you have to be in a new submission.

Comment: I am working on a new submission, and I edited the question with the screenshot when I click on English

Comment: Can you please check, there is no description and screenshots

Comment: @SreejithSree do not click on add/remove language. Immediately click on `English (United States)` that you can see in the first screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177410/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-nielsnet).